# Using JSON.NET in NET 5 (vNext)

Tags: asp.net, json

I am learning .NET 5 (vNext). I am doing this on my Mac OS X. I am trying to use JSON.NET in my project. Currently, I have the following:

**project.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "compilationOptions": {
        "warningsAsErrors": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.0"        
    },    

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

When I run `dnu restore` from the command line, I get the following error:

```
Restoring packages for /Users/me/MyProject/project.json
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Newtonsoft.Json'
Unable to locate Newtonsoft.Json >= 8.0.0
Writing lock file /Users/me/MyProject/project.lock.json
Restore complete, 114ms elapsed
Errors in /Users/me/MyProject/project.json
    Unable to locate Newtonsoft.Json >= 8.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Considering the error message, did you try verifying that the package exists with that version number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems self explanatory. There is no Newtonsoft.Json package with a version >= `8.0.0`.

The latest beta package is `7.0.1-beta3` and the latest stable package is `6.0.8`. Update your `project.json` accordingly.